# Add-PnPView - Show all items inside folder

Tags: powershell, pnp

I'm having an issue with creating a view on SP Online for a list to show all items inside folders. I can create the view with the filtering, but the option for the folders is not working.

```
$viewQuery = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Field_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>P180</Value></Contains></Where><QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/></QueryOptions>"

Add-PnPView -list $ListName -Title "View1" -Fields @("Name","Published Date") -Query $viewQuery
```

I can't seem to find any good examples of Add-PNPView with a query to do what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that CAML schema of the View does not support tag `<QueryOptions>`. This option is set as attribute in XML view element, like `<View Scope="Recursive" ....>`. On the other hand, command `Add-PnPView` requires to specify the **query** part of the view only .

Fortunately, you can set this option using the command `Set-PnPView`. Example:

```
Set-PnpView -List $listName -Identity $viewName -Values @{Scope=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewScope]::Recursive}
```